# SSL handshake failed error when trying to connect to MongoDB with Python client

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to connect to my shared MongoDB cluster, but I keep receiving the following error: SSL handshake failed: ac-ascvkib-shard-00-02.hkzvmvh.mongodb.net:27017: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

The exact code I'm using is below:

```
from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient

# I replaced <password> with my own password
uri = "mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@cluster0.hkzvmvh.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

# Create a new client and connect to the server
client = MongoClient(uri)

# Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I'm using Python 3.11 and I'm using pymongo==3.11. I'm on a windows machine, and it seems that the error message gets printed multiple times.

Comment: If the remote host forcibly closed the connection, you probably need to look at the logs from that end to see why it did that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide the Server CA certificate in the connection string

```
uri = "mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@cluster0.hkzvmvh.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&tlsCAFile=isrgrootx1.pem"
```

You can download the files from https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

I think it is this one: https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Wernfried Domscheit
You need to provide the Server CA certificate in the connection string **as well as download and place the file in the root directory of your project** in case you follow the example url. Otherwise you have to specify the path to the file.

No need to install the certificate into the OS

Answer (score 1):

The same issue was happening with me. I thought it's the certificate issue, but I found out that my current IP address was not added to the mongoDB access IP Network list.

Answer (score 1):

Simply just visit the network access tab from the MongoDBAtlas and add the IP address from the system you are trying to connect with MongoDB. [image]

Answer (score -2):

I recommend replacing `<password>` with your password.